# How do i use separate two integers using dot in java?

Tags: java, integer, java.util.scanner

I want to make a user to enter integers separated with dot like (11.56.98)
to use after that x=11 y=56 z=98

```
    `Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Your number like (36.52.10): ");
    int x = s.nextInt();
    int y = s.nextInt();
    int z = s.nextInt();`
```

now how to usedelimiter will change whitespace to dot and how to return to whitespace again

Comment: Take value in String and then divide the value as per ur requirement

Comment: could you please clarify what you want to do? Your last sentence is very hard to read and (at least for me) impossible to understand.

Comment: just use `string.split()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: [How do I use a dot as a delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369131/how-do-i-use-a-dot-as-a-delimiter) [How do I use a delimiter in Java Scanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766377/how-do-i-use-a-delimiter-in-java-scanner)

Comment: *"how to return to whitespace again"* ... you call `useDelimiter(...)` again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in the same line use: `s.next()`.

If you want the text in the next line you need to do: `s.nextLine()`

Whatever method you use it will return a `java.lang.String`.

You can use `String[] numbers = yourString.split(".")`

The array what you get if you split the string you can get all numbers:

```
int x = Integer.valueOf(numbers[0]);
int y = Integer.valueOf(numbers[1]);
int z = Integer.valueOf(numbers[2]); 
//Dont forget it can throw a NumberFormatException if the current String is not a valid number.
```